# In R, using ggplot + geom_bar, how do you vary the width of a bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am able to produce a barplot with variable binwidths using

```
byA<-barplot(table(A),width=B$length, space = 0,col="black")
```

[image: barplot with variable binwidths]

How might I do the same using ggplot?

I have tried this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(table(A)), aes(x=B$Start, y=Freq, width=B$length)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=B$length), stat="identity", position="identity")
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the spaces between bars and shift their position to start at 0 rather than be centered on the x markers? (I'm guessing this might get me the same barplot.) NB: I prefer the x-axis values as in the second plot, so that's fine.

These are the first 20 rows of my data:

```
    bin           Freq
1   [0,0.78)        9
2   [0.78,0.99)     1
3   [0.99,1.07)     1
4   [1.07,1.201)    1
5   [1.201,1.211)   0
6   [1.211,1.77)    3
7   [1.77,1.95)     0
8   [1.95,2.14)     2
9   [2.14,2.15)     0
10  [2.15,2.581)    0
11  [2.581,3.04)    4
12  [3.04,3.11)     0
13  [3.11,3.22)     0
14  [3.22,3.33)     1
15  [3.33,3.58)     3
16  [3.58,4.18)     8
17  [4.18,4.29)     2
18  [4.29,4.48)     4
19  [4.48,4.62)     4
20  [4.62,4.8)      3
```

Comment: try to adjust the width

Answer (score 1):

By using the `breaks` argument within `stat_bin` you can build the plot you
are looking for.

```
# We'll use the diamonds data set within ggplot2 for an example
library(ggplot2)

# Set breaks for the bars.  The bins are:
# 1st bin: [0, 100), centered at 50
# 2nd bin: [100, 500), centered at 300
# 3rd bin: [500, 1000), 
# 4th bin: [1000, 2000), 
# 5th bin: [2000, 5000), 
# etc.
# 
# to have (a, b] style intervals use the argument right = TRUE in the stat_bin
# call.
brks <- c(0, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 7500, 10000, max(diamonds$price))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price)) + 
geom_bar() + 
stat_bin(breaks = brks)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input - it tried adding stat_bin(breaks = brks) - changing brks to be the left side of my bin - but i get the error: stat_bin() must not be used with a y aesthetic. I know that I must be mixing up variables in the wrong order or including conflicting parameters for ggplot but I don't see my way out. I've included a small sample of the data.